# Dropbox API integration with Microsoft Mail Merge

Tags: ms-word, dropbox-api

I am trying to pass values to be shown in fields inserted in Microsoft Word documents or be an overlay (what is the correct word).  Can it be done?

Comment: Your question seems pretty vague and open ended. I recommend checking out the relevant documentation (e.g., https://www.dropbox.com/developers ) and trying to get started. If you run in to any specific problems, post a question with the details, code, etc.

Comment: This is not hard to understand.  Think of Mail Merge.  Can you pass values to a word document stored in dropbox via the api in order to achieve mail merge?

Comment: You can't selectively modify portions of a file on Dropbox remotely using the API, if that's what you mean. The API only allows you to upload new entire new versions. So you can download the file, modify it as desired, and upload the new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't selectively modify portions of a file on Dropbox remotely using the API, if that's what you mean. The API only allows you to upload new entire new versions. So you can download the file, modify it as desired, and upload the new version